# Substitute special character into blank space

Tags: regex, perl, sed, unicode, posix

do you have any idea to translate all special character into blank spaces

```
^@^@^@^@<9C>^G^@^@*+^@^@ABD
^@^@^@^@*+^@^@<DC>_^@^@ASD
^@^@^@^@*+^@^@<DC>_^@^@ASaa
^@^@^@^@<80><C2>^A^@<C2>p^A^@ABD
```

od

```
0000000 040136 040136 040136 040136 034474 037103 043536 040136
0000020 040136 025452 040136 040136 041101 005104 040136 040136
0000040 040136 040136 025452 040136 040136 042074 037103 057137
0000060 057100 040500 042102 057012 057100 057100 057100 025100
0000100 057053 057100 036100 041504 057476 040136 040136 041101
0000120 005104 040136 040136 040136 040136 034074 037060 041474
0000140 037062 040536 040136 041474 037062 057160 057101 040500
0000160 042102 000012
0000163
```

cat -vET

```
^@^@^@^@<9C>^G^@^@*+^@^@ABD$
^@^@^@^@*+^@^@<DC>_^@^@ABD$
^@^@^@^@*+^@^@<DC>_^@^@ABD$
^@^@^@^@<80><C2>^A^@<C2>p^A^@ABD$
```

I've tried

```
LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/[^[:blank:][:print:]]//g'
sed -r 's/[^[:print:]]//g'
```

or from this one https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336677/sed-and-remove-string-between-two-patterns

and the output not as expected

output

```
ABD
ASD
ASaa
ABD
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `od` of your file, or the output of `cat -vET`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic definition of a "*special character*" and you may need to specify what to keep -- so remove all characters other than those

```
$string =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9_,.-]//g;  # etc, spell out what to leave
```

and you can use the *word character* pattern `\w`

```
$string =~ s/[^\w,.-]//g;
```

where i've only given a few punctuation charters as example.

The *POSIX character class*, which you're trying to use, also work

```
$string =~ s/[^[:alnum:][:punct:]]/;
```

or using Perl extensions in the style of `\p` 
[Unicode properties](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html) for them

```
$string =~ s/[^\p{PosixAlnum}\p{PosixPunct}]//g;
```

where we can of course find actual Unicode properties as well, on the comprehensive page linked above.  Careful with the syntax; see "*POSIX Character Classes*" section in [perlrecharclass](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html).

Or perhaps you really mean to remove the non-printable characters

```
$string =~ s/[^[:print:]]//g;
```

---

To use this as a  command line program ("one-liner")

```
perl -wpe's/\W//g' file > new_file
```

to save the output as `new_file`, or

```
perl -i.bak -wpe's/[^[:print:]]//g' file
```

to change the file *in-place* (remove `.bak` if you don't want a backup).

If input is piped from another program

```
echo input | perl -wpe's/[^w,.-]//g'
```

Comment: It seems like you are attempting to peel the onion. The question is a bit unclear don't you think?

Comment: Also, the OP seems to be looking for a command-line solution so at the very least, you should metion that this is a Perl script fragment.

Comment: @kvantour I thikn that this is a very common question (with its non-specificity as well) and that it's useful to spell it out here

Comment: @zdim thanks a lot, for your deep understanding on my question, really appreciated

Comment: @user10254032 Welcome, and thank you for credit

Comment: @user10254032  It's a good question I think, and have no Idea what that -1 is for  (upvoted)

Comment: @user10254032 I've cleaned up around the use of POSIX character classes vs Unicode properties, and added another reference. Just letting you know...

Comment: wow, its getting neat, thanks a lot for your effort